# assimp not loading correctly

Tags: opengl, assimp

I'm a having problem loading meshes using Assimp. Some of the faces are not displayed even after ambient lighting. I'm using the code provided in the learnopengl.com tutorials for loading the mesh. I've included my Mesh and Model source below and the screenshot as well. If anyone can help with issue, I would really be very grateful.

Mesh.h

```
#pragma once
// Std. Includes
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
// GL Includes
#include <GL/glew.h> // Contains all the necessery OpenGL includes
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>


struct Vertex {
    // Position
    glm::vec3 Position;
    // Normal
    glm::vec3 Normal;
    // TexCoords
    glm::vec2 TexCoords;
};

struct Texture {
    GLuint id;
    string type;
    aiString path;
};

class Mesh {
public:
    /*  Mesh Data  */
    vector<Vertex> vertices;
    vector<GLuint> indices;
    vector<Texture> textures;

    /*  Functions  */
    // Constructor
    Mesh(vector<Vertex> vertices, vector<GLuint> indices, vector<Texture> textures)
    {
        this->vertices = vertices;
        this->indices = indices;
        this->textures = textures;

        // Now that we have all the required data, set the vertex buffers and its attribute pointers.
        this->setupMesh();
    }

    // Render the mesh
    void Draw(Shader shader)
    {
        // Bind appropriate textures
        GLuint diffuseNr = 1;
        GLuint specularNr = 1;
        GLuint reflectionNr = 1;

        for (GLuint i = 0; i < this->textures.size(); i++)
        {
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i); // Active proper texture unit before binding
            // Retrieve texture number (the N in diffuse_textureN)
            stringstream ss;
            string number;
            string name = this->textures[i].type;
            if (name == "texture_diffuse")
                ss << diffuseNr++; // Transfer GLuint to stream
            else if (name == "texture_specular")
                ss << specularNr++; // Transfer GLuint to stream
            else if (name == "texture_reflection")  // We'll now also need to add the code to set and bind to reflection textures
                ss << reflectionNr++;
            number = ss.str();
            // Now set the sampler to the correct texture unit
            glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.program, (name + number).c_str()), i);

            // And finally bind the texture
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->textures[i].id);
        }
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); // Always good practice to set everything back to defaults once configured.

        // Also set each mesh's shininess property to a default value (if you want you could extend this to another mesh property and possibly change this value)
        //glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "material.shininess"), 16.0f);

        // Draw mesh
        glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, this->indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

private:
    /*  Render data  */
    GLuint VAO, VBO, EBO;

    /*  Functions    */
    // Initializes all the buffer objects/arrays
    void setupMesh()
    {
        // Create buffers/arrays
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &this->VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &this->VBO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &this->EBO);

        glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);
        // Load data into vertex buffers
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO);
        // A great thing about structs is that their memory layout is sequential for all its items.
        // The effect is that we can simply pass a pointer to the struct and it translates perfectly to a glm::vec3/2 array which
        // again translates to 3/2 floats which translates to a byte array.
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &this->vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->EBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), &this->indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // Set the vertex attribute pointers
        // Vertex Positions
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)0);
        // Vertex Normals
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, Normal));
        // Vertex Texture Coords
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, TexCoords));

        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
};
```

Model.h

```
#pragma once
// Std. Includes
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
// GL Includes
#include <GL/glew.h> // Contains all the necessery OpenGL includes
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <SOIL.h>
#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>
#include <assimp/scene.h>
#include <assimp/postprocess.h>

#include "Mesh.h"

GLint TextureFromFile(const char* path, string directory);

class Model
{
public:
    /*  Functions   */
    // Constructor, expects a filepath to a 3D model.
    Model(GLchar* path)
    {
        this->loadModel(path);
    }

    // Draws the model, and thus all its meshes
    void Draw(Shader shader)
    {
        for (GLuint i = 0; i < this->meshes.size(); i++)
            this->meshes[i].Draw(shader);
    }

private:
    /*  Model Data  */
    vector<Mesh> meshes;
    string directory;
    vector<Texture> textures_loaded;    // Stores all the textures loaded so far, optimization to make sure textures aren't loaded more than once.

    /*  Functions   */
    // Loads a model with supported ASSIMP extensions from file and stores the resulting meshes in the meshes vector.
    void loadModel(string path)
    {
        // Read file via ASSIMP
        Assimp::Importer importer;
        const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs);
        // Check for errors
        if (!scene || scene->mFlags == AI_SCENE_FLAGS_INCOMPLETE || !scene->mRootNode) // if is Not Zero
        {
            cout << "ERROR::ASSIMP:: " << importer.GetErrorString() << endl;
            return;
        }
        // Retrieve the directory path of the filepath
        this->directory = path.substr(0, path.find_last_of('/'));

        // Process ASSIMP's root node recursively
        this->processNode(scene->mRootNode, scene);
    }

    // Processes a node in a recursive fashion. Processes each individual mesh located at the node and repeats this process on its children nodes (if any).
    void processNode(aiNode* node, const aiScene* scene)
    {
        // Process each mesh located at the current node
        for (GLuint i = 0; i < node->mNumMeshes; i++)
        {
            // The node object only contains indices to index the actual objects in the scene. 
            // The scene contains all the data, node is just to keep stuff organized.
            aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[i]];
            this->meshes.push_back(this->processMesh(mesh, scene));
        }
        // After we've processed all of the meshes (if any) we then recursively process each of the children nodes
        for (GLuint i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++)
        {
            // Child nodes are actually stored in the node, not in the scene (which makes sense since nodes only contain
            // links and indices, nothing more, so why store that in the scene)
            this->processNode(node->mChildren[i], scene);
        }

    }

    Mesh processMesh(aiMesh* mesh, const aiScene* scene)
    {
        // Data to fill
        vector<Vertex> vertices;
        vector<GLuint> indices;
        vector<Texture> textures;

        // Walk through each of the mesh's vertices
        for (GLuint i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; i++)
        {
            Vertex vertex;
            glm::vec3 vector; // We declare a placeholder vector since assimp uses its own vector class that doesn't directly convert to glm's vec3 class so we transfer the data to this placeholder glm::vec3 first.
            // Positions
            vector.x = mesh->mVertices[i].x;
            vector.y = mesh->mVertices[i].y;
            vector.z = mesh->mVertices[i].z;
            vertex.Position = vector;
            // Normals
            vector.x = mesh->mNormals[i].x;
            vector.y = mesh->mNormals[i].y;
            vector.z = mesh->mNormals[i].z;
            vertex.Normal = vector;
            // Texture Coordinates
            if (mesh->mTextureCoords[0]) // Does the mesh contain texture coordinates?
            {
                glm::vec2 vec;
                // A vertex can contain up to 8 different texture coordinates. We thus make the assumption that we won't 
                // use models where a vertex can have multiple texture coordinates so we always take the first set (0).
                vec.x = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].x;
                vec.y = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].y;
                vertex.TexCoords = vec;
            }
            else
                vertex.TexCoords = glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f);
            vertices.push_back(vertex);
        }
        // Now wak through each of the mesh's faces (a face is a mesh its triangle) and retrieve the corresponding vertex indices.
        for (GLuint i = 0; i < mesh->mNumFaces; i++)
        {
            aiFace face = mesh->mFaces[i];
            // Retrieve all indices of the face and store them in the indices vector
            for (GLuint j = 0; j < face.mNumIndices; j++)
                indices.push_back(face.mIndices[j]);
        }
        // Process materials
        if (mesh->mMaterialIndex >= 0)
        {
            aiMaterial* material = scene->mMaterials[mesh->mMaterialIndex];
            // We assume a convention for sampler names in the shaders. Each diffuse texture should be named
            // as 'texture_diffuseN' where N is a sequential number ranging from 1 to MAX_SAMPLER_NUMBER. 
            // Same applies to other texture as the following list summarizes:
            // Diffuse: texture_diffuseN
            // Specular: texture_specularN
            // Normal: texture_normalN

            // 1. Diffuse maps
            vector<Texture> diffuseMaps = this->loadMaterialTextures(material, aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, "texture_diffuse");
            textures.insert(textures.end(), diffuseMaps.begin(), diffuseMaps.end());
            // 2. Specular maps
            vector<Texture> specularMaps = this->loadMaterialTextures(material, aiTextureType_SPECULAR, "texture_specular");
            textures.insert(textures.end(), specularMaps.begin(), specularMaps.end());
            // 3. Reflection maps (Note that ASSIMP doesn't load reflection maps properly from wavefront objects, so we'll cheat a little by defining the reflection maps as ambient maps in the .obj file, which ASSIMP is able to load)
            vector<Texture> reflectionMaps = this->loadMaterialTextures(material, aiTextureType_AMBIENT, "texture_reflection");
            textures.insert(textures.end(), reflectionMaps.begin(), reflectionMaps.end());
        }

        // Return a mesh object created from the extracted mesh data
        return Mesh(vertices, indices, textures);
    }

    // Checks all material textures of a given type and loads the textures if they're not loaded yet.
    // The required info is returned as a Texture struct.
    vector<Texture> loadMaterialTextures(aiMaterial* mat, aiTextureType type, string typeName)
    {
        vector<Texture> textures;
        for (GLuint i = 0; i < mat->GetTextureCount(type); i++)
        {
            aiString str;
            mat->GetTexture(type, i, &str);
            // Check if texture was loaded before and if so, continue to next iteration: skip loading a new texture
            GLboolean skip = false;
            for (GLuint j = 0; j < textures_loaded.size(); j++)
            {
                if (textures_loaded[j].path == str)
                {
                    textures.push_back(textures_loaded[j]);
                    skip = true; // A texture with the same filepath has already been loaded, continue to next one. (optimization)
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!skip)
            {   // If texture hasn't been loaded already, load it
                Texture texture;
                texture.id = TextureFromFile(str.C_Str(), this->directory);
                texture.type = typeName;
                texture.path = str;
                textures.push_back(texture);
                this->textures_loaded.push_back(texture);  // Store it as texture loaded for entire model, to ensure we won't unnecesery load duplicate textures.
            }
        }
        return textures;
    }
};




GLint TextureFromFile(const char* path, string directory)
{
    //Generate texture ID and load texture data 
    string filename = string(path);
    filename = directory + '/' + filename;
    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    int width, height;
    unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image(filename.c_str(), &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
    // Assign texture to ID
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // Parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);
    return textureID;
}
```

Screenshots

[1st screenshot](http://s11.postimg.org/bvgkew9qb/crysis.png)

[2nd screenshot](http://s16.postimg.org/hfyvqsj2d/lady.png)

Comment: `using namespace std`, don't do this in a big or even semi-big project. Pollute the global namespace least possible.

Comment: Also, `#pragma once` does nothing in a source file

Comment: it was a header file actually...corrected it now...!!

Comment: can you add your solution for this please.

Comment: dead links. Can you reprovide them pls?

Answer (score 1):

as I can see here

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, this->indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

you draw all vertexes as triangles. And that is how you load indices from assimp

```
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < mesh->mNumFaces; i++)
    {
        aiFace face = mesh->mFaces[i];
        for (GLuint j = 0; j < face.mNumIndices; j++)
            indices.push_back(face.mIndices[j]);
    }
```

There is a problem here- face doesn't have exacly 3 vertexes (even if you use `aiProcess_Triangulate` when loading) which brokes drawing with `GL_TRIANGLES`. With `aiProcess_Triangulate` there will be faces with <= 3 vertexes (triangles and lines for example). You may ignore not triangle faces and that should fix drawing. Here is a fixed indeces filling cycle:

```
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < mesh->mNumFaces; i++)
    {
        aiFace face = mesh->mFaces[i];
        if (face.mNumIndices < 3) {
            continue;
        }
        assert(face.mNumIndices == 3);
        for (GLuint j = 0; j < face.mNumIndices; j++)
            indices.push_back(face.mIndices[j]);
    }
```

Comment: That didn't make any difference !

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but as I had the same problem, I thought this might help other people as well:

In my case my texture coordinates were not correct and the problem was in the lines

```cpp
vertices.push_back(mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].x);
vertices.push_back(mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].y);
```

In this case, we iterate over all vertices of an aiScene.
This lead in my case to your bug where not all faces were displayed.

Adding vertices via faces, however, fixed the issue for me:

```cpp
const aiScene *tree = _importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace | aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices | aiProcess_SortByPType);

// iterate over all meshes in this scene
for (unsigned int m = 0; m < tree->mNumMeshes; ++m) {
    const aiMesh *mesh = tree->mMeshes[m];
    // iterate over all faces in this mesh
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < mesh->mNumFaces; ++j) {
        auto const &face = mesh->mFaces[j];
        //normally you want just triangles, so iterate over all 3 vertices of the face:
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
            // Now do the magic with 'face.mIndices[k]'
            auto const &vertex = mesh->mVertices[face.mIndices[k]];
            vertices.push_back(vertex.x);
            vertices.push_back(vertex.y);
            vertices.push_back(vertex.z);

            // Same for the normals.
            auto const &normal = mesh->mNormals[face.mIndices[k]];
            vertices.push_back(normal.x);
            vertices.push_back(normal.y);
            vertices.push_back(normal.z);

            // Color of material
            // ...

            // And FINALLY: The UV coordinates!
            if(mesh->HasTextureCoords(0)) {
                // The following line fixed the issue for me now:
                auto const &uv = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][face.mIndices[k]];
                vertices.push_back(uv.x);
                vertices.push_back(uv.y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```